# How to pass pathname to

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, query-string

I am trying to pass 2 props in the routing , 1 is for the pathname of routing , 1 is for message to transfer to that page. But I found that the page is blank when I clicked the routing button . And when I refresh it, the page can show normally. How can I modify the code to fix that?
I tried to replace `props.location.search` to `props.pathname.location.search` . But still doesn't work.

This is the button I make for the routing

```
const [roomCode, setRoomCode] = useState('')
<Link to={{pathname: `/mahjongGame?roomCode=${randomCodeGenerator(4)}`, state: settingForm }}><button className="game-button yellow" >Routing Next Page</button></Link>
```

This is the page where button route to.

```
const MahjongGame = (props) => {
            const data = queryString.parse(props.location.search)
        
        //initialize socket state
        const [room, setRoom] = useState(data.roomCode)
        const [roomFull, setRoomFull] = useState(false)
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
        const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('')
        const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
        const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const connectionOptions =  {
                "forceNew" : true,
                "reconnectionAttempts": "Infinity", 
                "timeout" : 10000,                  
                "transports" : ["websocket"]
            }
            socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT, connectionOptions)
    
            socket.emit('join', {room: room, playerNum: 2}, (error) => {
                if(error)
                    setRoomFull(true)
            })
    
            //cleanup on component unmount
            return function cleanup() {
                socket.emit('disconnect')
                //shut down connnection instance
                socket.off()
            }
        }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `react-router-dom 6`. Have a look on this following working example.

[state and params](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-currying-xptshl?file=/src/Demo2.js)

Comment: I tried to access the data by console.log(state) , it gives me undefined . Maybe it's because I use hash router instead.